# Не удается получить количество записей с БД в Go

Tags: mysql, sqlite, golang, count

Проделывал с mysql и sqlite, результат один и тот же, количество не выводит, не пойму, в чем проблема?

```
 //db, errd := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./contacts.sqlite")  
    db, errd := sql.Open("mysql", "admin:pass@/test") 
    if errd != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT count(*)  FROM articles")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error!")
    }
    var count int
    err = rows.Scan(&count)
    fmt.Println("test ")
    fmt.Println(count)
    rows.Close()
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872429/i-cant-to-get-count-of-rows-in-db-in-go] проблема решена!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ошибка: Вы используете db.Query он вернет коллекцию объектов *sql.Rows; Что бы от туда получить данные надо:

```
defer rows.Close();
for rows.Next() {
   var count int64
   rows.Scan(&count)
}
```

Вторая ошибка: использовать int64 надо не int;

Третья ошибка: использовать отложенный вызов defer, он закроет соединение при любом исходе, конечно же вешать его после проверки на ошибку;

Рекомендация: Для выборки одного значения использовать: db.QueryRow(). Он уже вернет одно значение и можно делать так:

```
 var count int64
    err = rows.Scan(&count)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) 'rows.Scan(&count)' -> это справедливо, если делать дополнительный запрос в БД, что на мой взгляд излишне.

2) ниже вполне рабочий пример:

```
var count int
for rows.Next() {count++}
return count
```

3) 'var count int64' -> в данном случае можно и обычный int, позже проще использовать в коде.

4) count как я понял нужен для массива, но учитывая что rows имеет тип *sql.Rows, то смещение в переборе строк будет находиться в конце и повторно применить rows.Next() не получиться. Поэтому для получения строк использую не многомерный массив, а карту из массивов:

```
var mymap map[int][]string
mymap = map[int][]string{}

var temparray []string
columns, _ := rows.Columns()

i := 0
for rows.Next() {
   temparray = make([]string, len(columns))

   // Как динамически считывать данные со строк еще не нашел, 
   // кто найдет буду благодарен 
   _ = rows.Scan(&temparray[0], &temparray[1], &temparray[2])
   mymap[i] = temparray
   i++
}
return mymap
```

Comment: На этом ресурсе нет понятия - "дополнительный ответ". Рекомендую пройти [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).